# How to update Vue.js dependency version in Sails.js?

Tags: vue.js, sails.js, updates

I installed Sails.js `v1.0` as my Node.js framework to work with. I choose the `built-in web` for this Sails.js initialization. Then
I included Vuetify `v2.0.5` framework and it suggested me to update the Vue.js dependency `v2.5.17` in Sails.js into Vue.js `^v2.5.18`.
I don't want any warnings in my console and I want to get rid of it.

[image: warning message in console]

I expect my Sails Vue.js dependency has the latest version.

Comment: Why don't you update your Vue.js version from `2.15.17` to `2.5.18`? It's just a patch release, so nothing will break.

Comment: I don't know how to update my dependency in Sails Vue.js